# OpenRAVE IK fails to find a solution on Katana 6M90a arm

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ik, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a follow-up question to [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/866/how-to-use-openraves-ik-with-a-5dof-manipulator). I can now start the IK service, but it doesn't find a solution.

Steps to reproduce:

```
rosrun orrosplanning ik_openrave.py --scene=$(rospack find katana_description)/collada/katana6m90a.robot.xml
```

In a new terminal:

```
rosrun orrosplanning testarmik5d.py
```

Before doing that, I had to change "Base" to "katana_base_link" in the file `testarmik5d.py`. Also, I added a debug output to the end which prints out "IK failed to find a solution".

This is the output in the first terminal:

```
[openravepy_int.cpp:3096] viewer qtcoin successfully attached
initializing, please wait for ready signal...
[INFO] 1305727377.607870: setting map frame to katana_base_link
[INFO] 1305727377.636657: openrave services ready: /IK, /GetPositionIK
[INFO] 1305727453.084118: generating ik for <manipulator:arm, parent=katana6m90a>
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: Generating inverse kinematics for manip arm: TranslationDirection5D [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] (this might take up to 10 min)
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: creating ik file /home/martin/.openrave/kinematics.06a287e4f96075cb37e70ca665496409/ikfast41.TranslationDirection5D.0_1_2_3_4.cpp
openravepy.ikfast: moved translation [0, 0, -1473/10000] to right end
openravepy.ikfast: moved translation [0, 0, 0] to left end
openravepy.ikfast: moved translation on intersecting axis [0, 0, 0] to left
openravepy.ikfast: ikfast translation direction 5d: [j0, j1, j2, j3, j4]
openravepy.ikfast: attempting li/woernle/hiller general ik method
openravepy.ikfast: found non-singular AU matrix
openravepy.ikfast: solved coupled variables: [j0, j1, j2]
openravepy.ikfast: [j0, j1, j2] [j3, j4]
[...]
openravepy.ikfast: [j0, j1, j2, j3] [j4]
openravepy.ikfast: generating cpp code...
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: inversekinematics generation is done, compiled shared object: /home/martin/.openrave/kinematics.06a287e4f96075cb37e70ca665496409/ikfast41.TranslationDirection5D.x86_64.0_1_2_3_4.so
```

In the second terminal, I just see (my own) error message over and over:

```
IK failed to find a solution
...
```

Also, if I try to use the "Translation3D" IK type, OpenRAVE hangs for more than 20 minutes on a fast PC after printing "openravepy.ikfast: generating cpp code...". Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

As usual, the necessary files can be found in the [katana_description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/katana_description) package.

**EDIT:** Rosen's answer solved my question. For the benefit of later readers, here is what had to be changed:

*Before (incorrect):*

```
<direction>0 0 1</direction>
<translation>0 0 0</translation>
```

[image: incorrect manipulator direction]

*After (correct):*

```
<direction>1 0 0</direction>
<translation>0 0 -0.03</translation>
```

[image: correct manipulator direction]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9988/openrave-ik-fails-to-find-a-solution-on-katana-6m90a-arm/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, please change the direction and origin of the  tag as follows:

```
<direction>1 0 0</direction>
<translation>0 0 -0.03</translation>
```

when selecting the robot in openrave, you should see the black arrow normal to the gripper surface. this is the most useful form of 5D ik, and ik results are:

```
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: success rate: 0.890000, wrong solutions: 0.000000, no solutions: 0.110000, missing solution: 0.079000
```

You originally had it pointing toward the z-axis, which aligned with one of the joint axes. if you still need z-axis direction, i'll look into the problem and report.

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-18**:
Perfect, that solved it. Thanks a lot, OpenRAVE is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm Martin's assistant and just wanted to specifiy our problem a little bit, because I just discovered that the IK solver very rarely suceeded.

I'd run:

```
rosrun openrave openrave.py --database inversekinematics --robot=katana6m90a.robot.xml --usecached --iktests=1000 --iktype=translationdirection5d
```

with the following results:

```
 openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: success rate: 0.001000, wrong solutions: 0.002000, no solutions: 0.997000, missing solution: 0.000000
```

Maybe that helps, if anybody has an idea what could be wrong in our approach.

---

Originally posted by [Henning Deeken](https://answers.ros.org/users/554/henning-deeken/) with karma: 66 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2